# Sharepoint 2007 page without master page

Tags: sharepoint-2007

i would like to know how to create a page in sharepoint 2007 that has no masterpage. tks!

Comment: Do you mean that has no "site"?

Comment: hummm... no... i mean a page that has no masterpage... like... no sidebar, no global nav bar... nothing... i dont know how else to describe it... a page that has no masterpage...

Comment: Are you able to modify the source for the pages?

Comment: Yes i can... but i was looking for another solution if possible... because this will be avalible for the end-users... and they cannot be trusted...

Comment: Create the page using web interface or your own custom page?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Not technically. What business process are you trying to implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please create a Page Layout that **doesnt** inherit the master page and then create a page from that page layout. This is only applicable for MOSS 2007 with Publishing Feature enabled.

Sample Page Layout code is given below:

```
<%@ Page language="C#" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePointWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingNavigation" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SPSWC" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingNavigation" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="Welcome" src="~/_controltemplates/Welcome.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="DesignModeConsole" src="~/_controltemplates/DesignModeConsole.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="PublishingVariations" TagName="VariationsLabelMenu" src="~/_controltemplates/VariationsLabelMenu.ascx" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingConsole" TagName="Console" src="~/_controltemplates/PublishingConsole.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="PublishingSiteAction" TagName="SiteActionMenu" src="~/_controltemplates/PublishingActionMenu.ascx" %>

<head>
<meta name="ProgId" content="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document">
<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/core.css"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="init.js" runat="server"/>

</head>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div style="float=right; height=10px;">
<!-- Site Actions-->
<PublishingSiteAction:SiteActionMenu runat="server"/>
</div>
<div>
<!-- Page Editing Toolbar -->
<wssuc:DesignModeConsole id="IdDesignModeConsole" runat="server"/>
<PublishingConsole:Console runat="server"/>
</div>
<div>
    <WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager runat="server" id="WebPartManager">
    </WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager>
    <WebPartPages:WebPartZone id="g_6CCC1E01CED54C21AB5D59878B886105" runat="server" title="Zone 1">
    </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Open Site in SPD, right click on the root in "Folder List" pane and select "New" and then "ASPX". New aspx page in SharePoint without master page is created. In this page we can perform any of operation that SharePoint supports.